# admin_notices hook show message all admin pages after plugin activate

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am working on a plugin and in plugin i use `admin_notices` hook for showing my custom message. When a user activate plugin the message show blew the `plugin activate` successfully, but my message shows all the other admin pages.

I want to show message only the plugins page after plugin activate or my plugin settings page. I don't know how can i fix this.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'wpc_plugin_notices');
function wpc_plugin_notices() {
    $plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
    if (is_plugin_active($plugin)) {
        echo "<div class='updated'>
                <p>
                    Please go to this page
                    <a href='".site_url()."/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wpcproduct&page=image_resize&action=wpc_resize&products=1'>Click Here</a>
                </p>
              </div>";
    }
}
```

Please guide me how can i fix this.

Answer (score 3):

For do this you need to save in the db a value for remember that the alert was already showed.
Else you can try to llok on that https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook. With this you can execute an hook only on the activate action of the plugin.